# How to know if fullscreen is pressed in youtube_player_flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to run a function whenever the video player changes from normal view to fullscreen and vice versa.

This is my code

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mentors/models/video_model.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoModel videoModel;

  const VideoPlayer({super.key, required this.videoModel});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayer> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
  YoutubePlayerController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.videoModel.id,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    //To bring back status bar
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
      if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
        //Removes Status Bar When Full Screen
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                child: YoutubePlayer(
                  controller: _controller!,
                  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  onReady: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ));
      } else {
        //Brings Back Status Bar
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
            overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 40,
              ),
              YoutubePlayer(
                controller: _controller!,
                showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                onReady: () {},
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.videoModel.title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          DateFormat("dd MMM yyy")
                              .format(widget.videoModel.publishedAt),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "Description",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          widget.videoModel.description,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that as ı know, but take package to your local and you can add
`required void Function()? fullScreenOnPressed`
and give it to necessery widgets an you will achive what you want

Comment: Then I guess there are no default callback functions :(